# Is the Hadd punishment of Zina applicable if the sinner is of a young age?

Tags: zina, hudud

Asslamoalikum to all of my brothers and sisters

My question is that **if people commit zina at very early age (8-12 or basically under 18), will there be punishment of those of 100 lashes?**

And by the way just s*cking b**bs or l*ck*ing v*gina is considered zina or when a person loses his/her virginity before marriage is considered zina or both things considered zina.

Comment: The Hadd for Zina by an unmarried person is 100 lashes, not 80, see [24:2](https://quran.com/24/2).

Comment: You may find [How deep does the penis need to be inside before its classed as zina and is subject to hadd punishment?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37176/how-deep-does-the-penis-need-to-be-inside-before-its-classed-as-zina-and-is-sub?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Classification of zina in difficult situations](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37176/how-deep-does-the-penis-need-to-be-inside-before-its-classed-as-zina-and-is-sub?noredirect=1&lq=1) useful.

Comment: You mean zina is considered zina only when men's whole penis goes into the women's vagina?

Answer (score 1):

One of the conditions for applying the Hadd punishment is that the perpetrator must be accountable, it does **not** apply to a child below the age of puberty.

> #### رفع القلم عن ثلاثة عن النائم حتى يستيقظ وعن الصبي حتى يحتلم وعن المجنون حتى يعقل
>
> The pen has been lifted from three: a sleeper till he awakes, a boy till he reaches puberty, and a lunatic till he comes to reason.
>
> <sup>— [Abu Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/40/53)</sup>

> لا حد على الزاني والزانية إلا بشروط، منها متفق عليه، ومنها مختلف فيه، وهي عشرة
>
> الأول ـ أن يكون الزاني بالغا، فلا يحد الصبي غير البالغ بالاتفاق
>
> There is no Hadd on the fornicator and fornicatress except when certain conditions are met. Some of them are agreed upon and in some there is disagreement. And these are ten conditions:
>
> First ـ That the fornicator be an adult, hence there is consensus that there will be no Hadd on a child.
>
> <sup>— [الفقه الإسلامي وأدلته](https://shamela.ws/book/384/5198)</sup>

However a person below 18 years may still be considered an adult in Islam if he\she has reached puberty, in which case the Hadd will apply if other conditions are met.

The Hadd applies for the form of Zina in which the head of the penis has disappeared into the vagina or the anus (See the answers [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/40018/20218) and [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/37205/20218)) - it does not apply to any other act. Such acts may however carry a Ta'zir punishment.

Comment: Isn't anal penetration prohibited in Islam?

Comment: @Ahmed Yes it is.