# Is touching a nonmehram zina?

Tags: sunni, zina, non-mahram

Touching hands and face. And letting nonharam touch your hand and face. Touching his hair or touching his arm..is this all included in zina?

Answer (score 1):

Zina , that needs 4 witnesses and is punishable with  "Hadd" punishment , is the penetration. Other than that : it Haram , and it's degree of 'Haram' differs from one action to another. They are called : "things that lead to Zina" , which are for example : touching with sexual lust(desire) , looking with sexual lust  .. and so on.

see : https://islamqa.info/en/27259

and God knows best

Comment: What extent is considered for non punishable zina?

Comment: Feeling pressure on the vagina and anus is penetration?

Comment: Feeling that glans might have entered the vagina or anus is punishable zina or nonpunishable zina?

Comment: "In the case of zina, the hadd punishment is conditional upon penetration, which means that the head of the penis disappears into the vagina. If it does not penetrate it or only part of it penetrates it, then he is not subject to the hadd punishment.  "

https://islamqa.info/en/76052

Comment: @AyeshaAslam you are asking a totally new question in the comment section, you should rather ask it, although there's an answer on that on the ite https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37176/how-deep-does-the-penis-need-to-be-inside-before-its-classed-as-zina-and-is-sub/37205#37205