# What constitutes anal intercourse?

Tags: punishment, zina, homosexuality, fatwa-explanation, hudud

What constitutes anal intercourse? Even though it is a sin to have sex from the back passage in Islam whether it is male or female but how much of the penis should penetrate for the hadd to be applicable. I have read Fatwas on this site as well as many known Islamic sites that at least the glans of the penis must disappear fully. If partly or hardly the tip or urethra is touching it doesn't constitute. Again it is a sin but the hadd is not applied in such a case?

Comment: I don't see any fatwa here (deleted wrong tag). The answer of the title question is basically the same as [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/37176/13438). However you've asked many questions which is rather misleading on our site. As most of these questions have answers and we can't close a Multi-question post as none of the duplicates will cover the whole post.

Comment: Thank You, Brother. I have seen the answer and read your comment. I am going to delete this question after some time. I'm taking the answer to the above question as a NO (Intercourse doesn't take place according to the above scenario). If I am wrong just correct me in the comments.

Answer (score -1):

"It is not a condition of repentance that the hadd punishment be carried out on the repentant person. He should conceal himself with the concealment of Allaah, Achieving sincere repentance is better than confessing so that the hadd punishment may be carried out."

Copied from islamqa

"This person has repented well and has given back to people what is rightfully theirs, so he should not let the Shaytaan come and spoil his repentance.In the case of zina, the hadd punishment is conditional upon penetration, which means that the head of the penis disappears into the vagina. If it does not penetrate it or only part of it penetrates it, then he is not subject to the hadd punishment.

It says in al-Mawsoo’ah al-Fiqhiyyah (24/23),."

Copy pasted from islamqa

Using same analogy i think hadd punsihment is only applicable if the head of the penis disappears in anus not giving a fatwa though.

Comment: Brother Hamza, Appreciate your effort to address this question. After days of searching and questioning Its almost confirmed that the head of the penis should disappear for hadd to be applicable and All 4 School of thoughts unanimously agree in this case as well. The analogy you prefer is valid.